# Data-driven SSRS security

Tags: reporting-services

Say we have a Project Status Report in SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS 2012) that takes the Project ID as the parameter, how can we secure the report so that only team members of that project can see the result?

We have the team members for every project in a separate table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the userID as a parameter to your SQL query using query parameters and assigning user id by using command User!UserID. Then inside your SQL query you can check the privileges by using your team member table and return data accordingly